# Opening a bounty then realizing it was a dup

Tags: discussion

I've put a bounty here:

[Copying and Pasting into NotePad++ and preserving colours/Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509340/pasting-into-notepad-and-preserving-colours-styles)

Then I realized that the question can be a dup, and the other has already a very good answer:

[Copy Notepad++ text with formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475790/copy-notepad-text-with-formatting)

I tried to flag the question as a dup, but I cannot.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Flag the post for moderator attention and explain the situation. Most likely the bounty will be discarded (either by the moderator or by waiting for the bounty to expire), after which you can vote to close as a duplicate if the moderator hasn't closed it already for you.

Comment: Those don't look like duplicates to me, they're opposites. The one you put a bounty on asks about pasting formatted text into notepad++, the other about copying from notepad++ with syntax highlighting.

Comment: @OGHaza: only in the title. The body of the question is saying: "how to **copy and paste** some code into Notepad++ and preserve all the styles and colors of the pasted text?" -> so it's a partial dup. But there is also another question about pasting which is dup of this.

Comment: Keyword: **into**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag your question for moderator attention using an "other" type flag. Then clearly explain the situation, linking to the duplicate.

A moderator can then check if the bounty indeed could be cancelled and refunded, while closing the question as a duplicate. Or you could do so in case the bounty has merely been removed.