# How to behave on partial answer dup?

Tags: discussion

Imagine you find a Question asking for two things (let's call them questions), having been a answered with a normal quality answer.

Then you find a second answer addressing only the first of the two questions but with a really beautiful answer.

What is the best way to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: Ignore.  Why mark the question as a duplicate of one with an awful answer?  (Optional: downvote the awful answer.)

Comment: That edit was something.

Comment: Ideally the OP should not ask 2 questions in a single post. You could leave a comment stating that.

Comment: Sorry, I used a wrong english term I modified the question. I want to say to who sees the first Question (with the two sub questions) to look also the other link

Comment: @Bart: but it's not my most big concern.. My concer is about spreading the better answer to who see the worst one.. (sorry for my english)

Comment: Would you happen to have a practical example of such a situation?

Comment: Have a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222923/opening-a-bounty-then-realizing-it-was-a-dup the 1st asks for copy and pasting, the second gives a really good answers only for the copying question..

Comment: related: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/165773) Multi-q posts are better be closed, to let asker re-design them into proper format without fear of invalidating answers. Generally, _too broad_ reason is a better fit but in cases like you describe, dupe closure is worth considering too, as it [offers a more concrete guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773 "see eg here") to asker on how to improve

Comment: @gnat: yes.. I agree with you that too broad is not going to explain why we are closing the answer. He would have to guess the real reason. Also because copy&paste are not that different except for this specific tool..